Generating SAS account token in powershell
"I generated a token using Azure and it’s working, but I need to create a correct script in PowerShell using the key. The stringToSign I generated is different from the one provided by Azure, and azcopy gives me a 403 Server failed to authenticate the request error. The base for the script is:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/create-account-sas
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/eventhub/generate-sas-token
# Azure Storage Account Details
$storageAccountName = "name"
$storageAccountKey = "key"
$baseUrl = "https://$storageAccountName.blob.core.windows.net"

# SAS Token parameters
$permissions = "rwdlacup"  # Read, write, delete, list, add, create, update, process
$serviceVersion = "2022-11-02"  # API version
$expiryDate = "2024-12-13T22:41:13Z"  # Token expiry
$startDate = "2024-12-13T14:41:13Z"   # Start time
$signedServices = "bqtf"  # Blob, Queue, Table, File
$signedResourceTypes = "sco"  # Service, Container, Object
$signedIP = ""             # No specific IP restriction
$signedProtocol = "https"  # Only HTTPS

# Create the string-to-sign
$stringToSign = "$storageAccountName\n$permissions\n$signedServices\n$signedResourceTypes\n$startDate\n$expiryDate\n$signedIP\n$signedProtocol\n$signedversion"

# Compute HMAC SHA-256
$hmac = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA256
$hmac.Key = [Convert]::FromBase64String($storageAccountKey)
$sig = [Convert]::ToBase64String($hmac.ComputeHash([Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($stringToSign)))

# Construct SAS token
$sasToken = "?sv=$serviceVersion&ss=$signedServices&srt=$signedResourceTypes&sp=$permissions&se=$expiryDate&st=$startDate&spr=https&sig=$sig"

# Full URL with SAS token
$fullUrl = "$baseUrl/$sasToken"

I tried different types of stringToSign, but the SAS token is still different and results in the same error. The SAS token generation is not matching, and I receive the 403 Server failed to authenticate the request error. I have tried using various stringToSign formats, but none have worked as expected.

Please share how you are using this SAS URL.

Check the below answer.


Generating SAS account token in powershell

If you are using 2022-11-02 REST API version your stringToSign  should be constructed using the following logic:
StringToSign = accountname + "\n" +  
    signedpermissions + "\n" +  
    signedservice + "\n" +  
    signedresourcetype + "\n" +  
    signedstart + "\n" +  
    signedexpiry + "\n" +  
    signedIP + "\n" +  
    signedProtocol + "\n" +  
    signedversion + "\n" +
    signedEncryptionScope + "\n"

You can use the below script to generate account sas token using Powershell.
Script:
# Parameters
$xMsDate = [System.DateTime]::UtcNow.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ")
$expiryInSeconds = 7200 # 2 hours validity

$accountName = "xxx"
$signedPermissions = "rwdlaciytfx"
$signedService = "b"
$signedResourceType = "sco"
$signedStart = $xMsDate
$signedExpiry = [System.DateTime]::UtcNow.AddSeconds($expiryInSeconds).ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ")
$signedIP = "" # Optional
$signedProtocol = "https"
$signedVersion = "2022-11-02"
$signedEncryptionScope = ""

# Storage Account Key (Replace with your actual key)
$accessKey = "xxxx"

# Construct String-to-Sign
$StringToSign = "{0}`n{1}`n{2}`n{3}`n{4}`n{5}`n{6}`n{7}`n{8}`n{9}`n" -f `
    $accountName, $signedPermissions, $signedService, $signedResourceType, `
    $signedStart, $signedExpiry, $signedIP, $signedProtocol, $signedVersion, $signedEncryptionScope

# Decode the storage account key
$keyBytes = [Convert]::FromBase64String($accessKey)

# Convert String-to-Sign to bytes
$SignatureBytes = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($StringToSign)

# Generate HMAC-SHA256 signature
$hasher = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA256
$hasher.Key = $keyBytes
$Signature = [Convert]::ToBase64String($hasher.ComputeHash($SignatureBytes))

# Generate SAS Token
$sasToken = "sv=$signedVersion&ss=$signedService&srt=$signedResourceType&sp=$signedPermissions&se=$signedExpiry&st=$signedStart&spr=$signedProtocol&sig=$([System.Web.HttpUtility]::UrlEncode($Signature))"

# Output the SAS Token
Write-Output $sasToken

Output:
sv=2022-11-02&ss=b&srt=sco&sp=rwdlaciytfx&se=2024-12-14T11:27:45Z&st=2024-12-14T09:27:45Z&spr=https&sig=redacted


Now, I verified the SAS token with blob URL to fetch the image from the Azure blob storage.
API request:

Reference:
Create an account SAS - Azure Storage | Microsoft Learn
